# Optimal number of parallel processes for computation with a CPU with 6 cores and 12 threads

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, cpu, cpu-cores

On a computer with an Intel CPU marketed "6 cores / 12 threads", I want to run as many processes as possible, each of them doing math similar computations (each process has a single thread) with different input data. There is no GPU involved, and no inter-process communication is needed.

**What is the optimal number of parallel processes of the same executable doing math computations?**

Should I run 6 processes (one per physical core)? Or 12 processes (one per thread / virtual core)?

If one process does, say, 1000 computations per second, I'm pretty sure that running 6 of them will run at ~1000/sec each (so a total of ~6000/sec).

But won't running 12 processes make them only 500 computations per second each?

**TL;DR:** should I run one process per "core" or one process per "thread" on a "6 cores/12 threads Intel CPU"?

Comment: depends on what these processes are going to do. If this is a CPU-bound workload, then 6 processes will be a few percent faster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is very dependent of the actual computing code**. Some application can benefit from hyper-threading while some do not. High-performance application rarely benefit from hyper-threading so using 1 process per core is certainly the best configuration assuming the code is compute bound and scale well.

Multiple hyper-threads of recent Intel processors (eg. Skylake/Icelake) can **share some execution ports**. As a result, the overall execution can be faster if one process is not able to saturate the ports. In practice, this is a bit more complex (modern processor are *very* complex) since compute-bound processes can be bound by other part of the processor like instruction decoding or more tricky low-level units.

For example, the following C code should benefit from hyper-threading (assuming no fast-math optimizations are applied and the code is compiler with optimizations):

```c
float sum = 0.f;
for(int i=0 ; i<maxi ; ++i)
    sum += array[i];
```

Indeed, the latency of a floating-point addition instruction is 3 to 4 cycles while generally 2 of them can be executed per cycle (only 1 before Skylake). This means the code is bound by the latency of the addition instruction chain. Hyper-threads can use the waiting execution port during this time resulting in a up to twice faster execution (other bottleneck cause the execution not to be so fast in practice). If the code is optimized with fast-math optimization, then compilers can unroll the loop and make use of *instruction-level parallelism* (IPC). **A low IPC often means that using hyper-thread may be beneficial, especially if the cause of this low IPC is due to latency issues** (eg. instruction latency and cache misses). Unfortunately, this is not always true. For example, the following code should not be faster with hyper-threading:

```c
for(int i=0 ; i<maxi ; ++i)
    out_array[i] += in_array[i];
```

This is because there is generally 1 execution store port on Intel processor and it should already be saturated with 1 hyper-thread (otherwise it should be memory throughput bound which is not better for hyper-threading). Thus using more hyper-thread should not improve the execution time. In fact, hyper-threading introduces a slight overhead that should cause a slightly slower execution.

The thing is applications are generally much more complex than that and one does not know how math functions are implemented. A a result, **this is nearly impossible for a developer to know what is the best configuration without a basic benchmark unless the computing kernel is simple**.